# Trivia game: The answers from an array are not properly coming up as correct or incorrect.

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The link to the code can be found here:  [Codepen link](http://codepen.io/lafrish/pen/OXoKOj)

The questions is chosen at random from the triviaPrompts array. However, the answers are coming out incorrectly when selected.

For example: The correct answer to this question was B: Maracana Stadium. However, prompt for wrong answer appears and shows option C as the correct answer.
 [image: screenshot of trivia game]

html:

```
<div class="container" id="start">
  <div class = "question"></div>
  </br>
  <div id="answers">
  </br>
    <div class= "answer span" id= "A"></div>
    <div class= "answer span" id= "B"></div>
    <div class= "answer span" id= "C"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="score"></div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <div class = "right-or-wrong" style = "display:none"></div>
  </br>
    <div class = "next" style = "display:none">Next question!</div>
      <div id="score again"></div>
        </div>

<div class="cd-popup" role="alert">
    <div class="cd-popup-container">
        <p> You got nothing right</p>
        <ul class="cd-buttons">
            <li id="reset"><a href="#start">Play Again</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cd-popup1" role="alert">
    <div class="cd-popup1-container">
    <img src="css/bronze-short.png" />
    <p> You got 1 out of 3 correct. </br>Good job!</p>
        <ul class="cd-buttons">
            <li id="reset"><a href="#start">Play Again</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cd-popup2" role="alert">
    <div class="cd-popup2-container">
    <img src="css/silver-short.png" />
    <p>You got 2 out of 3 correct.</br>Awesome job!</p>
        <ul class="cd-buttons">
            <li id="reset"><a href="#start">Play Again</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cd-popup3" role="alert">
    <div class="cd-popup3-container">
    <img src="css/gold-short.png" />
            <p>You got 3 out of 3 correct.</br>Perfection!</p>
        <ul class="cd-buttons">
            <li id="reset"><a href="#start">Play Again</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var clickCount = 0;
var questionCount = 0;
var score = 0;
var i = 0;
var reloading = document.getElementById('reload');
var setScore = function() {
  if (clickCount < 1) {
    $(".score").html("<p>Score:" + score + "</p>");
  }
};
function reset(){
  $('#reset').on('click', function (){
    addQAs();
    setScore();
    chooseAnswer();
  })
};

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  //open popup
  $('.cd-popup-trigger').on('click', function(){
    // event.preventDefault();
    $('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
  });

  //close popup
  $('#reset').on('click', function(){
    $('.cd-popup').removeClass('is-visible');
    reset()
  })

  $(document).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.which=='27'){
      $('.cd-popup').removeClass('is-visible');
    }
  });
});


var triviaPrompts = [
  [ "How many times have the Olympics been held in South America before 2016?", ["Once", "Twice", "Never"], "C", ["A", "B"] ],
  [ "Which events are included for the first time in decades?", ["Golf & Cycling-BMX", "Rugby & Golf", "Rugby & Cricket"], "B", ["A", "C"] ],
  [ "What is lit with a flame during the opening ceremony?", ["The Olympic Cauldron", "The Olympic Mascot", "The Olympic Torch"], "C", ["A", "B"] ],
  [ "The torch relay began on April 21st in which city?", ["Olympia", "Rio de Janeiro", "London"], "A", ["B", "C"] ],
  [ "Organizers prepare approximately how many meals per day to feed athletes?", ["5,000", "60,000", "30,000"], "B", ["A", "C"] ],
  [ "Which is one of the venues for the Rio Olympics?", ["The Olympic Golf Course", "The Olympic Village", "The Olympic Parade"], "A", ["B", "C"] ],
  [ "The first refugee team to ever compete at the Olympic Games competes under which flag?", ["Olympic", "Greece", "Brazil"], "A", ["B", "C"] ],
  [ "Which two types of martial arts are represented in the Summer Olympics?", ["Kung Fu & Tai Chi Chuan", "Karate & Ninjitsu", "Taekwondo & Judo"], "C", ["A", "B"] ],
  [ "The beach volleyball tournament is held at?", ["Fort Copacabana", "Copacabana Beach", "The Copacabana Club"], "B", ["A", "C"] ],
  [ "Where are the opening and closing ceremonies held?", ["Joao Havelange Olympic Stadium", "Maracana Stadium", "Maracanazinho Arena"], "B", ["A", "C"] ],
  ["How many gold medals will be handed out during at the 2016 Summer Olympics?",
  ["306", "256", "400"], "A", ["B", "C"] ],
  ["What is the motto for the 2016 Summer Olympics?", ["One World. One Dream.", "Light the Fire Within", "Live your passion"], "C", ["A", "B"] ],
  ["What is the estimated cost in U.S. dollars of the 2016 Summer Olympics?", ["$6.25 billion", "$11.25 billion", "$22.25 billion"], "B", ["A", "C"] ],
  ["When will the 2016 Summer Games end?", ["October 15th", "September 2nd", "August 21st"], "C", ["A", "B"] ],
  ["Rio's taxi drivers, or 'taxistas', were given the chance to sign up for free online English lessons provided by the Rio 2016 Organizing Committee?", ["True", "False", " "], "A", ["B", "C"] ],
  ["There will be a total of 28 sports in the 2016 Summer Olympics?", ["True", "False", " "], "A", ["B", "C"] ],
  ["The official mascots of the 2016 Summer Olympics are Vinicius and Tom?", ["True", "False", " "], "A", ["B", "C"] ],
  ["There will be less than 10,000 athletes participating in the 2016 Summer Olympics?", ["True", "False", " "], "B", ["A", "C"] ]
];

function addQAs (){
  var questionCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * triviaPrompts.length);
  $(".question").text(triviaPrompts[questionCount][0]);
  $("#A").text( triviaPrompts[questionCount][1][0] );
  $("#B").text( triviaPrompts[questionCount][1][1] );
  $("#C").text( triviaPrompts[questionCount][1][2] );
};


var chooseAnswer = function(){

  var rightAnswer = function() {
    if (clickCount < 1) {
      $(this).css("color", "green"); // (1)
      $("#" + triviaPrompts[questionCount][3][0]).css("color", "grey");
      $("#" + triviaPrompts[questionCount][3][1]).css("color", "grey");
      $(".right-or-wrong").show();
      $(".right-or-wrong").text("You are correct!");
      score = score + 1;
    }
    setScore();
    clickCount++;
    $(".next").show();
  };

  var wrongAnswer = function () {
    if (clickCount < 1) {
      $(".answer").css("color", "grey");
      $(this).css("color", "red");
      $(".right-or-wrong").show();
      $(".right-or-wrong").text("That is wrong! The correct Answer is " +  $("#" + triviaPrompts[questionCount][2]).text() + ".");
      clickCount++;
      $(".next").show();
    }
  };

  var answerChoices = function() {
    $(".answer").off("click");
    $("#" + triviaPrompts[questionCount][2]).on("click", rightAnswer);
    $("#" + triviaPrompts[questionCount][3][0]).on("click", wrongAnswer);
    $("#" + triviaPrompts[questionCount][3][1]).on("click", wrongAnswer);
  };
  answerChoices();
};


var onNext = function(){
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (triviaPrompts.length));
  questionCount++;
  if ( questionCount <= (triviaPrompts.length-1)) {
    addQAs();
    $(".right-or-wrong").hide();
    $(".next").hide();
    $(".answer").css("color", "white");
    clickCount = 0;
    chooseAnswer();
  }

  if ( questionCount == 3 ) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      if (score=== 3){
        $('.cd-popup3').addClass('is-visible');
      } else if ( score === 2) {
        $('.cd-popup2').addClass('is-visible');
      } else if  (score ===1){
        $('.cd-popup1').addClass('is-visible');
      } else {
        $('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
      }
    })
  }
}

$(".next").on("click", onNext);
$("html").on("keydown", function(e){
  if ($(".next").css("display") !== "none"){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      onNext();
    }
  }
});

addQAs();
setScore();
chooseAnswer();
reset();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the correct answers by taking var out of addQAs function: old code

```
function addQAs (){
  var questionCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * triviaPrompts.length);
  $(".question").text(triviaPrompts[questionCount][0]);
  $("#A").text( triviaPrompts[questionCount][1][0] );
  $("#B").text( triviaPrompts[questionCount][1][1] );
  $("#C").text( triviaPrompts[questionCount][1][2] );
};
```

new and working code:

```
function addQAs (){
  questionCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * triviaPrompts.length);
  $(".question").text(triviaPrompts[questionCount][0]);
  $("#A").text( triviaPrompts[questionCount][1][0] );
  $("#B").text( triviaPrompts[questionCount][1][1] );
  $("#C").text( triviaPrompts[questionCount][1][2] );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, update rightanswer function as below

```
var rightAnswer = function() {
    if (clickCount < 1) {
      $("#" + triviaPrompts[questionCount][2]).css("color", "green"); // replace this code
      $("#" + triviaPrompts[questionCount][3][0]).css("color", "grey");
      $("#" + triviaPrompts[questionCount][3][1]).css("color", "grey");
      $(".right-or-wrong").show();
      $(".right-or-wrong").text("You are correct!");
      score = score + 1;
    }
    setScore();
    clickCount++;
    $(".next").show();
  };
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/xOybEo

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the wrong results. The correct answers are in the array for reference.

Comment: There are few syntax errors and wrong usage of variables like variable questioncount is for getting random question but it is being used in place of click count with if condition I.e if(questioncount =3) instead of click count count and resetting click count to zero